# Filtrar um array de objetos dentro de outro array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, orientação-a-objetos, filter

Eu tenho um array como o abaixo e gostaria de filtrar ele pela propriedade que esta dentro de um objeto dentro de um array que ta dentro de outro objeto.

A ideia seria retornar todos os objetos cujas movimentações sejam tipo: "saida".

Em outra pergunta no fórum encontrei este codigo e o adaptei para minha circunstância :) A solução deles foi:

```
var filtrado = array.filter(function(obj) { return obj.marcar == 1; });
```

Como eu filraria por movimentações que sejam tipo: "saida"

```
    var array = 
    [
        {
            conta_id : "7",
            movimentações: { InternaMov : [
               {data: "20/10/1029",
                tipo: "saida",
                valor: "300,00"},
               {data: "19/10/1029",
                tipo: "entrada",
                valor: "900,00"}
            ]},
            marcar : 1,
            pag_data_emissao : "04/08/2015",
            pag_debito_credito : "D",
            pag_historico : "CHEQUE 331107  VENDA S",
            pag_id : "47782",
            pag_utilizado :"VENDA S",
            pag_valor : "7.000,00"
        },
        {
            conta_id : "7",
            movimentações: { InternaMov : [
               {data: "20/10/1029",
               tipo: "saida",
               valor: "300,00"},
               {data: "19/10/1029",
               tipo: "entrada",
               valor: "900,00"}
            ]},
            marcar : 0,
            pag_data_emissao : "07/08/2015",
            pag_debito_credito : "D",
            pag_historico : "DEPOSITO 3117  VENDA X",
            pag_id : "47783",
            pag_utilizado :"VENDA X",
            pag_valor : "640,63"
        }
    ];
```

Comment: Mas você quer retornar só o objeto mais interno ou quer retornar as informações do externo e o objeto interno filtrado?

Answer (score 2):

Existem duas soluções para resolver o seu problema. A primeira é caso você só queira as movimentações, que daí você faria da seguinte forma:

```
array.map(obj1 => (obj1.movimentacoes.InternaMov.filter(obj2 => obj2.tipo === 'saida')));
```

```js
var array = 
    [
        {
            conta_id : "7",
            movimentacoes: { InternaMov : [
               {data: "20/10/1029",
                tipo: "saida",
                valor: "300,00"},
               {data: "19/10/1029",
                tipo: "entrada",
                valor: "900,00"}
            ]},
            marcar : 1,
            pag_data_emissao : "04/08/2015",
            pag_debito_credito : "D",
            pag_historico : "CHEQUE 331107  VENDA S",
            pag_id : "47782",
            pag_utilizado :"VENDA S",
            pag_valor : "7.000,00"
        },
        {
            conta_id : "7",
            movimentacoes: { InternaMov : [
               {data: "20/10/1029",
               tipo: "saida",
               valor: "300,00"},
               {data: "19/10/1029",
               tipo: "entrada",
               valor: "900,00"}
            ]},
            marcar : 0,
            pag_data_emissao : "07/08/2015",
            pag_debito_credito : "D",
            pag_historico : "DEPOSITO 3117  VENDA X",
            pag_id : "47783",
            pag_utilizado :"VENDA X",
            pag_valor : "640,63"
        }
    ];
    
console.log(array.map(obj1 => (obj1.movimentacoes.InternaMov.filter(obj2 => obj2.tipo === 'saida'))));
```

Caso você queira manter as informações do objeto externo, daí você deve fazer a seguinte alteração no `map`:

```
array.map(obj1 => ({...obj1, movimentacoes: obj1.movimentacoes.InternaMov.filter(obj2 => obj2.tipo === 'saida')}))
```

```js
var array = 
    [
        {
            conta_id : "7",
            movimentacoes: { InternaMov : [
               {data: "20/10/1029",
                tipo: "saida",
                valor: "300,00"},
               {data: "19/10/1029",
                tipo: "entrada",
                valor: "900,00"}
            ]},
            marcar : 1,
            pag_data_emissao : "04/08/2015",
            pag_debito_credito : "D",
            pag_historico : "CHEQUE 331107  VENDA S",
            pag_id : "47782",
            pag_utilizado :"VENDA S",
            pag_valor : "7.000,00"
        },
        {
            conta_id : "7",
            movimentacoes: { InternaMov : [
               {data: "20/10/1029",
               tipo: "saida",
               valor: "300,00"},
               {data: "19/10/1029",
               tipo: "entrada",
               valor: "900,00"}
            ]},
            marcar : 0,
            pag_data_emissao : "07/08/2015",
            pag_debito_credito : "D",
            pag_historico : "DEPOSITO 3117  VENDA X",
            pag_id : "47783",
            pag_utilizado :"VENDA X",
            pag_valor : "640,63"
        }
    ];

console.log(array.map(obj1 => ({...obj1, movimentacoes: obj1.movimentacoes.InternaMov.filter(obj2 => obj2.tipo === 'saida')})));
```

Perceba que no primeiro exemplo apenas filtramos os arrays internas, enquanto no segundo exemplo, copiam-se todas as propriedades do objeto dentro de `array` e filtra-se apenas os arrays internos.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe Avelar... Valeu mesmo.

Comment: @AlessandroCunhalorenz se essa solução resolveu seu problema, poderia marcar como resposta, por favor?